# Finding the overlap between direction of distance in position space and direction of distance in velocity space

Tags: calculus, geometry, statistics, algorithms, physics

There are two objects A and B that can be described in position space and velocity space.  The position space describes the instantaneous positions of the objects while the velocity space describes the rate of change in position of the objects.  They are both of uniform density in both position and velocity space.  For each individual object the location of one of its points in position space is unrelated to that point location in velocity space and vice verse.  Both objects are perfect spheres in both position and velocity space.

The center of object A in position space has coordinates ($X_A$, $Y_A$, $Z_A$), and the center of object A in velocity space has coordinates ($v_{X_A}$, $v_{Y_A}$, $v_{Z_A}$).

The center of object B in position space has coordinates ($X_B$, $Y_B$, $Z_B$), and the center of object B in velocity space has coordinates ($v_{X_B}$, $v_{Y_B}$, $v_{Z_B}$).

Object A has a volume of $V_A$ in position space and a volume of $V_{v_A}$ in velocity space.  Object B has a volume of $V_B$ in position space and a volume of $V_{v_B}$ in velocity space.

Now we can take pairs of points from the two objects, in which each point has coordinates in position space and coordinates in velocity space, and in which one point is from object A and one point is from object B.  These pairs of points have a displacement between the points in position space and a velocity between the points in velocity space.  My first question is how do I calculate the fraction of pairs of points, in which the displacement between the points in position space is within 1cm of being in the same direction as the velocity between the points in velocity space?  My second question is how do I calculate the fraction of pairs of points, in which the velocity between the points in velocity space is within 1cm/s of being in the same direction as the displacement between the points in position space?

Comment: I cannot make any sense of the sentence "They are both of uniform density in both position and velocity space." Can you possibly clarify? There is no uniform density on 3-space, for one thing.

Comment: @JohnHughes What do you mean by the statement "There is no uniform density on 3-space, for one thing."?  I would clarify the sentence "They are both of uniform density in both position and velocity space." but I'm not sure what you find confusing about it.

Comment: If you have a uniform probability density on the reals, it has to be a constant function whose integral over the reals is 1; there's no such thing. As for the other statement, "they are both" was the confusing part: it's not clear what is means for an object $A$ to be uniform in position space, as its center of mass has only one position. Or if it means that the points of $A$ are uniformly distributed in position space...then that doesn't make sense because of the lack of a uniform distribution (even on $\mathbb R$).

Comment: @JohnHughes what I meant by uniform density is that the mass of object A is evenly distributed within object A.  Also the mass of object B is evenly distributed within object B.  When I say "they are both" I mean that for each object the mass is evenly distributed within that object and not that the two objects necessarily have the same density as each other nor that the objects mass is evenly distributed between the objects.  I hope that clears up the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

1. The only sphere in 3-space whose image in velocity space at some point "has uniform density" in the sense described in the answers to comments above...is in purely translational motion, not rotation.
2. The "direction of the distance in position space" is presumably a unit vector, computed by taking $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ for $v$ the displacement vector. The same goes for the direction of the distance in velocity space. Unfortunately, unit vectors don't come with units like "cm", so the first question doesn't really make sense. (And nor does the second, of course).

It appears to me that this question needs a little bit of refinement.

Comment: I just edited my post to say "displacement between the points in position space" and "velocity between the points in velocity space" instead of "direction of distance" as direction of distance sounds a lot more like a unit vector,  I also I changed the words " the same as" to "in the same direction as" given that same direction just shows that the directions are the same without implying that they have the same magnitudes as "the same as" implies.  I hope that makes it easier to answer.

Comment: The units on the two vectors are still different: one is in cm, the other in cm/sec; you can't compare them in a meaningful way.  And this doesn't address point 1. As I said, I think that the question needs further work. You might try to work out an analogous example in one dimension for yourself: the objects will be intervals, all vectors will be parallel, so the vector-ness of things won't matter, and you can just do the work with at most one-variable calculus. When you've worked out such an example, you might want to include it in your question so that others know what you're hoping for.

Comment: Even though the units are different it is still possible to find the angle between the vectors using the formula $$cosS=\frac{\vec{r}*\vec{v}}{||\vec{r}||||\vec{v}||}$$ with $\vec{r}*\vec{v}$ as the dot product of the vectors, ||\vec{r}|| as the length of the displacement vector, and ||\vec{v}|| as the length of the velocity vector.

Comment: After this it is possible to construct two SAS triangles.  Both triangles would have the angle between the velocity and displacement as the angle.  For one of the triangles one of the given sides would be the displacement while the other given side would be a vector with the same units and magnitude as the displacement but in the same direction as the velocity.  For the other triangle one of the given sides would be the velocity while the other would be a vector with the same magnitude and units as the velocity but the direction of the displacement.

Comment: Next the sides opposite the angle S or the angle between the displacement and velocity could be found using the law of cosines and then it would be possible to look at whether these sides are less than or equal to 1cm and 1cm/s.  The problem is I'm not sure how to use this formula to figure out what fraction of the pairs of points fit this criteria.  I am also aware of the point 1 you made and its implications but keep in mind we are talking about the instantaneous position of the points in this case not how their velocity will effect their future positions.

Comment: The statement I made about spheres *applies to instantaneous position.* And while you can, as you observe, look at the angle between the displacement and speed-displacement vectors, that angle is unitless, so trying to compare it to 1cm or 1 cm/s is hopeless. Best of luck clarifying your thinking and your question so that others will get engaged and try to help you.